# How do you change the geom_point size based on two variables?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, shapes

I have this data called `df`. I need to change the size of the shapes based on the proportion of `Nucleotides` and their respective `Percent` values. For example, if A have overall percent higher than all other Nucleotides, I want to make A appear bigger than G, T or C. My code below plots all the variables, but I couldn't manage to change the size of Nucleotides based on the corresponding percent values. I would really appreciate if someone could help me with their expertise on this!

data:

```
df<- structure(list(Pos = c(9, 9, 22, 9, 12, 1, 5, 21, 17, 10, 18, 
15, 13, 10, 12, 23, 15, 6, 5, 2, 8, 10, 3, 9, 4, 16, 19, 6, 23, 
1, 20, 22, 19, 18, 11, 20, 11, 8, 13, 16, 9, 9, 18, 9, 10, 20, 
3, 10, 6, 6), Nucleotides = structure(c(1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 
2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("A", 
"C", "G", "T"), class = "factor"), Percent = c(1.25, 0.550314465408805, 
20.0731497418244, 0.995604395604396, 0, 1.00671140939597, 2.03009876156137, 
0.436898024029391, 0, 0.126082666374301, 0.137827450633918, 0.0728332119446468, 
0.13412531136233, 0.488293476899962, 0.606980273141123, 4.5262817940713, 
0.873737176736748, 2.09909875651215, 1.13913751017087, 0.330169211721007, 
0.305810397553517, 0.18524604858227, 1.25, 0.183503959822291, 
0.443521668065556, 0.601235873740466, 0.404688430512696, 0, 1.69868233052866, 
0.955167790489426, 1.2019531739076, 1.08638871657579, 0.691915513474144, 
3.44827586206897, 0, 25.6706562113083, 0.440528634361234, 0.203389830508475, 
0.547150411280846, 0.348986173079472, 1.26238676129117, 0.554843839731413, 
0.55041831792162, 0.180733779143322, 0.509484245179495, 1.31092996173682, 
0.651041666666667, 0, 0.182417582417582, 0.38268672472948), Samples = structure(c(9L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 10L, 9L, 4L, 5L, 10L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 8L, 11L, 
4L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 7L, 9L, 7L, 3L, 7L, 11L, 10L, 2L, 11L, 1L, 
8L, 6L, 9L, 10L, 5L, 10L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 8L, 3L, 8L, 11L, 4L, 2L, 
5L, 10L, 3L, 5L), .Label = c("Ago2_SsHV2L_1_CATGGC_L003_R1_001", 
"Ago2_SsHV2L_2_CATTTT_L003_R1_001", "Ago4_SsHV2L_1_CCAACA_L003_R1_001", 
"Ago4_SsHV2L_2_TAATCG_L003_R1_001", "Dcl1_SsHV2L_1_GTAGAG_L003_R1_001", 
"Dcl1_SsHV2L_2_GGTAGC_L003_R1_001", "Dcl2_SsHV2L_1_ATGAGC_L003_R1_001", 
"Dcl2_SsHV2L_2_CAAAAG_L003_R1_001", "WTDK3_SsHV2L_1_GACGAC_L003_R1_001", 
"WTDK3_SsHV2L_2_TACAGC_L003_R1_001", "WTDK3_SsHV2L_3_TATAAT_L003_R1_001"
), class = "factor"), Read.Length = c("24", "18", "22", "20", 
"18", "23", "20", "24", "23", "22", "21", "24", "19", "24", "19", 
"23", "21", "23", "18", "20", "19", "24", "24", "23", "21", "20", 
"21", "23", "24", "23", "24", "23", "24", "19", "24", "20", "23", 
"20", "21", "21", "20", "21", "22", "19", "20", "21", "18", "22", 
"20", "21")), .Names = c("Pos", "Nucleotides", "Percent", "Samples", 
"Read.Length"), row.names = c("9.A63", "9.C8", "22.T4", "9.G17", 
"12.G64", "1.C62", "5.G24", "21.C20", "17.C69", "10.T26", "18.T18", 
"15.T42", "13.T23", "10.A7", "12.G51", "23.G21", "15.G25", "6.G27", 
"5.G1", "2.C31", "8.A9", "10.T49", "3.C63", "9.T48", "4.G18", 
"16.C45", "19.A63", "6.G69", "23.T4", "1.C76", "20.G5", "22.G23", 
"19.C36", "18.C58", "11.C70", "20.T21", "11.A69", "8.T38", "13.C4", 
"16.C18", "9.G52", "9.C18", "18.C54", "9.T72", "10.C24", "20.G7", 
"3.G29", "10.T68", "6.T17", "6.A32"), class = "data.frame")
```

code:

```
p <- ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(aes(x=Pos, y = Percent, color = Read.Length,group = Samples, shape = Samples, size = Nucleotides))+
  scale_shape_manual(values=1:nlevels(df$Samples)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1,seq(2,24,2)))+ 
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank()) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("lavender", "darkslategray2", "darkseagreen4", "yellow", "blue", "red","deeppink4"))+
  theme(text = element_text(size=12),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, hjust=1))+
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=14),
        axis.title=element_text(size=14,face="bold"))
p
```

Comment: Ok. That is fine

Comment: always happy to remove my downvote as specified in the link too. I don't do anonymous downvotes, matter of courtesy, and giving the chance to improve your post. let me know when (if doing so) you should have improved it. - also, advice, not only your data frame is too big. Also your ggplot call contains too many unnecessary lines. All the Layout specs are not relevant

Comment: Thanks, but the codes I have are not redundant. There is no other way I could have replicated the problem with lesser data and codes in this post.

Comment: I disagree. You can cut down to fewer variables, and less observations. Simply cutting down the df with head(df,20) massively reduces the code and does not really change the figure. But I would also suggest in future replacing your long names with variable placeholders, for future references

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question well, your code already does what you want. Size mapping is based on the overall percentages. The code below shows that "A" has the lowest overall percentage value while "T" has the highest one.

```
df2 <- df %>% 
  group_by(Nucleotides) %>% 
  mutate(overall_percent = sum(Percent))
```

However, having many shapes may be confusing. `facet_grid` or `facet_wrap` could be of help with the extra dimension in this case. For example, you can use color mapping for *Samples* and faceting for *Read.Length* so that your size mapping is more visible with points.